# jQuery animate loop not working properly

Tags: jquery, html

```js
          for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
              $('#container').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, function () {
                  $(this).text('Just Do It.');
              }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 1000, function () {
                  $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, function () {
                      $('#container').text('Nike');
                      $('#container').animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 1000);
                  });
              });
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Nike</div>
```

```js
              $('#container').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, function () {
                  $(this).text('Just Do It.');
              }).animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 1000, function () {
                  $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 1000, function () {
                      $('#container').text('Nike');
                      $('#container').animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 1000);
                  });
              });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">Nike</div>
```

So the goal of my code was to successfully loop a fade in and fade out effect except by using opacity and animate, The code without the for loop runs fine by itself but as soon as I try to loop it, it just keeps looping the "just do it" part, if anyone could help me figure this out it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT---------**

Is this a reason you need the for loop? For loops are usually used when you want to run the statements and check the conditions a particular number of times. Not when you want the code block to continuously execute.

I achieved your desired result by housing your strings in a variable setting the index and incrementing `.eq` sets the 0 position for the index the showNextText function handles the index switching.

```js
(function() {

    var text = $(".text");
    var textIndex = -1;
    
    function showNextText() {
        ++textIndex;
        text.eq(textIndex % text.length)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .delay(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000, showNextText);
    }
    
    showNextText();
    
})();
```

```css
.text {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Nike</div>
<div class="text">Just Do It.</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't the break make it so it just stops looping after the first time? The problem i'm having is that the loop for some reason only repeats the Just Do It part for some reason..

Comment: @Durubie, yes the break; terminates the for loop. So you want this to loop continuously?

Comment: I want it to loop what happens in the second snippet continuously, the goal is to have it fade in and out of "Nike" & "Just Do It" over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

```js
var i = -1;
var x = -1;
var max = 100;
var txt = ["Nike", "Just Do It", "BMW"];

anim();

function anim() {
  if (x == max) return;
  x++;
  i++;
  if (i == txt.length) {
    i = 0;
  }

  $('#container').animate({
    'opacity': 0
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).text(txt[i]);
  }).animate({
    'opacity': 1
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(this).animate({
      'opacity': 0
    }, 1000, anim);
  });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much! a bit sad i had to scrap my code, but this works well so ill use it.